# Dependent visa for Masters students in Germany

Tags: visas, germany

I am an Indian citizen. My husband is admitted as a Masters student at TUM and I intend to join him there.

When I contacted the Bangalore consulate, they flatly refused saying 'You can not travel as a dependent if your husband is a Masters student.'
When I contacted the Mumbai consulate, they said 'Of course you can travel with your husband. You just need to show funds in your bank account.'
 - Two contradictory views.

On their website there is no clear mention of whether such applications are even accepted. However, for the 'family reunion visa' they mention a list of documents, among them a 'Certificate of residence (“Meldebescheinigung”) of the spouse living in Germany'.

Does anyone have any additional information about dependent visas for spouses of Masters students?

Answer (score 2):

Your situation is that you are visiting someone already in Germany; so you need to apply for the appropriate visa type.

The family reunion visa you mention is for permanent residents of Germany that wish to bring their family members to reside with them permanently in Germany.

*Your husband probably has a German National Visa (which is for longer term stays, like for study).*

The types of (short stay) visas are listed [at the embassy's website](http://www.india.diplo.de/Vertretung/indien/en/06__Consu__Visa/visa__new/SCHENGEN/SCHENGEN__VAC.html), along with their requirements.

From that list, for the purpose of your visit - you need to apply for a visit visa, the requirements for which are listed on this [pdf](http://www.india.diplo.de/contentblob/4002772/Daten/3548293/visit.pdf).

Comment: Your answer is not correct. Any residence permit (including those for students) allows for a family reunion. See [§ 29 Abs. 1 Nr. 1 AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0369). There are quite a lot of international students using that. Even better: In case the marriage was done before getting the student permit and the permit is still valid for at least one year and the spouse speaks basic German there is a *legal entitlement* for a family reunion by § 30 Abs. 1 S. 1 Nr. 3 Lit. e.

Comment: But it is in so far correct that if you just want to *visit* instead of move, you need a regular Schengen short-stay visa. As long as you can prove that you will return it should be no problem to get that compared to other premises.